# R data download from URL help w/timeout

Tags: r, timeout, download

I am downloading data from a URL using R with the following code;

```
setInternet2(TRUE)
URL <- paste(t1,dbegin,t2,dend,t3,sep="")
temp <- tempfile() # get data into a temp file
download.file(URL, temp)
```

I get the error/warning "the operation timed out".

I've tried adding
1) options(timeout=200), no effect even if I set timeout to 10000
2) loading RCurl library and using "getURL" instead

Interestingly, if I take the text string for the URL I'm trying to download and copy/paste into a browser, it downloads fine. The files I'm trying to download are not large (500kB zip files). Any help/suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to read data then save them to your drive.

```
URL = 'https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/databases/synthetic_control/synthetic_control.data'
sc <- read.table(URL, header = F, sep = "")
write.table(sc, file='synthetic_control.data')
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach Polla, thank's for the suggestion. Unfortunately (for me) they are ZIP files.

Comment: If I may add here.... the "URL" text does not refer directly to a ZIP file, it is a long string of API text that can be used for downloading data from the CAISO OASIS web site (energy price data). So it appears to be a command given to the OASIS site which then returns (and downloads) a ZIP file. If you take the text string referred to by "URL" and paste it into a browser, it downloads the file. If you use download.file referring to this text string, it fails. So.. within R are there options I need to set in the download.file command? Or is there  separate method that should be used? Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure if it is redirection or not. But if it is possible could you please provide one of the URLs that you are using to download these zip files.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Setting the following option fixed the issue for me:

```
 options(download.file.method="libcurl", url.method="libcurl")
```